# How to calculate the moving average of a binary value with no arrays or while/for statments

Tags: math, average

I've got a binary object (in my case it represents a valve).
I want to calculate a value that represents its average (or estimated average) value over the last hour.

I'm doing this calculation in a language called PPCL, which was created for controlling HVAC equipment.
It script language that doesn't use arrays, there is no for statement, or while statement.
I don't want to create 60 variable and sampling the value every 60 seconds, since I would end up with hundreds of variables with the multiple valves I've got to average.

Thanks

Comment: How estimated can it be? One simple method is to take the weighted average of the last average and the new value to obtain a new average, and doing that with each new value you get. It's not a moving average, it gives more weight to more recent values, but you can tune it to give decent results.

Comment: Doing a 1:20 weighted average between the new value and the previous "average" means that the latest value added will represent about 5% of the "average" (when it should be 1.7%), and will drop to 0.28% by the time it's 59th in line.

Comment: I've trouble to figure the binary object you have. Is that like a stream containing a value that regularly changes (every minute if I understood well) and for which you've no record of the past values?

Comment: The weighted average may do the trick, estimated is ok...How do I do that without looking back to past values?

The binary object is a value that I can read however often I want. No ability to go to read past values outside of whatever I can do in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
`TIMAVG(output,sampleTime,numSamples,thingToAverage)` function in PPCL to calculate moving averages.
Make sure that every pass of the program hits this line, and that there is no SAMPLE() on that line.